# Troubleshooting 'undefined variable' error

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the following error `Undefined variable: password on line 33` how do I correct this problem? So this error will stop showing.

Here is the php code.

```
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $purifier->purify(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['first_name']))));
$password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $purifier->purify(strip_tags($_POST['password1'])));
$password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $purifier->purify(strip_tags($_POST['password2'])));




// Check for a password and match against the confirmed password:
if ($password1 == $password2) {
    $sha512 = hash('sha512', $password1);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $sha512);
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">Your password did not match the confirmed password!</p>';
}



//If the table is not found add it to the database
if (mysqli_num_rows($dbc) == 0) {
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
        $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO users (user_id, first_name, password) 
                                     VALUES ('$user_id', '$first_name', '$password')");
}



//If the table is in the database update each field when needed
if ($dbc == TRUE) {
        $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE users 
                                     SET first_name = '$first_name', password = '$password' 
                                     WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");

        echo '<p class="changes-saved">Your changes have been saved!</p>';

}
```

Comment: its `WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");`

Answer (score 1):

There's only one place where a value is assigned to `$password`

```
if ($password1 == $password2) {
    $sha512 = hash('sha512', $password1);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $sha512);
}
```

So, if the condition isn't met there will be no `$password`. And in that case it doesn't make sense to perform the UPDATE query anyway.

Comment: well then it should display `echo '<p class="error">Your password did not match the confirmed password!</p>';` instead of an error.

Comment: Initialize `$password`.  Add `$password = '';` above it all.

Comment: Imo there's a lot to fix. E.g. all that `$purifier->purify(htmlentities(strip_tags(...)))` stuff, you seriously should reevaluate that, don't just apply any/everything you can throw at those strings in hope something will do the trick. Do something useful instead, e.g. testing if the password is somewhat "strong". Right now a password like "" or "a" is accepted despite all that mumbojumbo. Or that "if the insert fails try an update" part. Your script should really know whether a new user record is created or an existing record is to be updated at this point.

Answer (score 1):

At the top define

```
$password = '';
```

then change the DBC check to

```
if ($dbc == TRUE && $password != ''){
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the database insert is done whether the first `if()` was true or false. If it's false ($password1 and $password2 doesn't match), $password won't be defined.

Answer (score 0):

If this condition fails:

```
 if ($password1 == $password2) {
```

`$password` will not get defined, raising an error in one of the lines it is used in later.

Answer (score 0):

You don't raise an ERROR with an ELSE statement on the $password = ...... line so there is clearly an error there and it's not being defined.  The top level if statement is fine, but the error is on the $password declaration line.  Do you see how that works?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of retrying the query if the insert fails (presumably because the user_id already exists - you've made that your primary key?), you could use the alternate [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, first_name, password) 
VALUES ('$user_id', '$first_name', '$password')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    first_name=VALUES(first_name),
    password=VALUES(password)
```

On a nitpicky point, your comments say "if the table is not found" and "if the table...". You're not dealing with table creation/modification - you're working with records that are stored in a table.